# Solve for $\mu$ in $\epsilon^\frac32=\mu^\frac32+\frac{(\pi k_B T)^2}{8}\frac1{\sqrt\mu}$

Tags: calculus, physics

$$\epsilon^\frac32=\mu^\frac32+\frac{\left(\pi k_B T\right)^2}{8}\frac1{\mu^\frac12}$$
I am given that $\epsilon\approx\mu$ and $(1+x)^\alpha\approx1+\alpha x$ when $x\to0$.

I have tried manipulating this to
$$1-\frac{8}{(\pi k_B T)^2}\mu^\frac12(\epsilon^\frac32-\mu^\frac32)=0\Leftrightarrow\left[1+\mu^\frac12(\epsilon^\frac32-\mu^\frac32)\right]^{-\frac{8}{(\pi k_B T)^2}}=0$$
but this doesn't seem to lead anywhere.
any hints please?

the solution is one of these $T_f=\epsilon/k_B$:
[image]

Comment: I think it would end up being the root of a quartic equation, which isn't very neat.

Comment: In principle, you can write $x=\sqrt{\mu}$, rearrange to get $x^4-\epsilon^{3/2} x+(\pi k_B T)^2/8=0$, and solve using the quartic formula. But this is almost certainly not what you're expected to do; rather, you presumably should find $\mu$ as some kind of series expansion (in powers of $k_B T$, perhaps, since $\epsilon\to \mu$ as $k_B T\to 0$.)

Comment: Are you looking for a closed form solution?

Comment: yes! please read the post again, i have attached a picture. @PedroIgnacioMartinezBruera

Comment: @Luyw You are probably expected to write $\mu = \epsilon (1+x)$ where $x$ is small because $\epsilon \approx \mu$ then use the binomial approximation and solve for $x$.

Comment: The simplest solution is probably to plug in each of those answers in turn and see which one works. (In the sense of being correct to the desired order in $T/T_f$.) Also, should it be $\epsilon_f$ in your equation?

Comment: P vs NP. See which one satisfies the equation and pick that one

Comment: You can solve for μ by solving $μ^{3/2}+Βμ^{-1/2}-C=0$ where B and C are constants in your title which are constants with respect to μ. Fraction MathJax makes this looks worse.

Comment: @Semiclassical yes.

Comment: To simplify the "checking": One of the possible solutions has inconsistent units and can be ignored. The others are of the form $\mu=\epsilon_f(1+\alpha (T/T_f)^2)$ for various $\alpha$. So plug that in as your ansatz and use the binomial approximation to get rid of irrelevant terms.

Comment: @Semiclassical https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/solving-for-a-variable-in-an-equation-with-fractional-powers.1002586/post-6486816

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\epsilon^\frac32=\mu^\frac32+\frac{\left(\pi k_B T\right)^2}{8}\frac1{\mu^\frac12}$$

Let $b=\frac{\left(\pi k_B T\right)^2}{8}$ and croos mulitiply to make
$$f(\mu)=\epsilon ^{3/2}\sqrt{\mu }-\mu ^2-b=0$$  Now, since you are told that $\epsilon\approx\mu$, expand $f(\mu)$ as a series around $\mu=\epsilon$. This gives
$$f(\mu)=-b-\frac{3}{2} \epsilon  (\mu -\epsilon )+O\left((\mu -\epsilon )^2\right)$$ Neglecting the higher order terms
$$\mu=\epsilon -\frac{2 b}{3 \epsilon }=\epsilon  \left(1-\frac{2 b}{3 \epsilon ^2}\right)$$ Just continue and introduce $T_f$.